# using loop to print out input strings after inputing all of them

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

My problem is that I need to convert all of inputs after I type in the last one.  There is a function in the code which says: you type a number pocet_r and it allows you to type pocet_r strings. So and I need to change it somehow.

example, how it works now:

```
3 (`pocet_r`)
input 
output
input
output
input
output
```

and I want:

```
3 (`pocet_r`)
input 
input 
input
output
output
output
```

my code, look at highlighted loops, thats what is wrong:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;
int pocet_r;
void Convert(string input){
    string output = "";
    string flag = "";
    bool underscore = false;
    bool uppercase = false;
    if ( islower(input[0]) == false){
        cout << "Error!" <<endl;
        return;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < input.size(); i++){
        if ( (isalpha( input[i] ) || (input[i]) == '_') == false){
            cout << "Chyba!" <<endl;
            return;
        }
        if (islower(input[i])){
            if (underscore){
                underscore = false;
                output += toupper(input[i]);
            }
            else
                output += input[i];

        }
        else if (isupper(input[i])){
            if (flag == "C" || uppercase){
                cout << "Chyba!"<<endl;
                return;
            }
            flag = "Java";
            output += '_';
            output += tolower(input[i]);

        }
        else if (input[i] == '_'){
            if (flag == "Java" || underscore){
            cout << "Chyba!" <<endl;
            return;
            }
            flag = "C";
            underscore = true;
        }

    }


    for (int i=input.size()-1; i >=0; i--){
      if (input[i] == '_'){
            if (flag == "Java" || underscore){
            cout << "Chyba!" <<endl;
            return;
            }
            flag = "C";
            underscore = true;
        }
    }
    **for (int i = 0; output[i] != '\0' ; i++){

    cout << output[i] << endl; }**



} 



int main(){

    const int max = 100;
    string input;


    cin >> pocet_r;

    if(pocet_r >= 1 && pocet_r <=100)
    {
               for (int i = 0; i <pocet_r; i++)
               {
                if(input.size() > max){
                 cout << "slovo musi mat minimalne 1 a maximalne 100 znakov" << endl;
                 while(input.size() > max){

                                    **getline(cin, input);
                                    }**
                 }else{

                       Convert (input);
                       }





               }
    }else{
     cout << "Minimalne 1 a maximalne 100 uloh" << endl;
}
system("pause");
}
```

this code is doing something like, when I type a number 4, I get four messages saying Error!
, I dont even type four input strings...

EDITED, according to LoPoBo answer

```
}else{


                       for(vector<string>::iterator it = inputs.begin(); it != inputs.end(); ++it){
                       inputs.push_back(input);
                       Convert(*it);

                       }

}
```

Comment: Go through your code step by step and track in mind the current value of `input`. This will show you why you get to the `Error!` line. Think about when `getline` is executed the first time.

Comment: @Nabla, I see, but I have no idea how is should look like, I tried to move it around but I still get error..

Comment: @feri, if you know what the problem is and you used the method I described, then you could outline the procedure and your thoughts in the question. Together we could then try to modify things such that you get the result you want. Trial and error is not the way to go. Even better you write down the content of each variable for each step in the program flow. (Which is essentially what a debugger would do for you)

Comment: @Nabla, I would be happy If you can help me with my updated question, please

Comment: @Nabla I learn faster and better when I see a code that works, thats why I want to see a code from you for example, then I remember it. So please, ..I already tried to check it, but I dont see anything whats wrong.

Comment: @Nabla Im asking you for help, youre not helping me at all, thank you, Im working on this program for  a week, trying to learn something, but Im getting sick of it, .. reading such comments ... youre not any help, sorry..

Comment: Here are some problems, that you could easily find by applying the debugger method I described (or by using an actual debugger): 1. You test the size of `input` before you read something into it. 2. `Convert (input);` is never executed if `input.size() > max` initially. Do you need the `if(input.size() > max)` at all? You also check the same in the loop. 3. You only want to `inputs.push_back(input);` while you are in the loop and you want to reiterate over all inputs with `for(vector<string>::iterator it = inputs.begin(); it != inputs.end(); ++it)` after the first loop to call `Convert`.

Comment: @Nabla, would you please vote up my post? I cant ask questions because its voted down..please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not fully understand your code but if you want to read all the inputs before the outputs are computed, you can simply store the inputs in a std::vector.
Then, after all inputs are read, you can loop through the vector and do the computing, like this:

```
vector<string> inputs;
// Loop through the inputs and add them to the vector with inputs.push_back(input);
for(vector<string>::iterator it = inputs.begin(); it != inputs.end(); ++it){
Convert(*it);
}
```

See also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: thanks, I can add now strings and I dont get output right away, but I dont get it at all now :/

Comment: I can't comment your question so I write this here:
I think you misunderstood my answer. Change `Convert(input)` in your original code to `inputs.push_back(input)`.
Then, after this loop, all the inputs that should  be converted will be in `inputs` and then you can make a new loop (the one i wrote in the answer).
I think there are some other bugs in the program though, but I'm not sure what it is supposed to do. For example, you never read a value to `input` unless `input` have more than 100 characters (which it never will since you never read to it).

Comment: thanks a lot, my code is working already, I had to chill a little and then I understood what you meant, thanks anyway and please, vote up my question.